# How to send Android GCM cloud notification without server?

Tags: android, wordpress, notifications

I implemented an android application. I don't have server. I got json response from wordpress JsonApi. My website was developed by using wordpress. I want to send notifications to my android application users. I don't have server and database to store android device GCM id and send notification. Is there any way to send notification to users those who are using my android application. can anyone please explain me how can i send notification to my android application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A website is served by a server so you do have a server. Maybe you just don't manage it.

In your situation, I'd use a GCM plugin for wordpress.
Try this:
https://github.com/wp-plugins/wp-gcm

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. The above you mentioned plugin  is not a freeware. Can u please send me a freeware plugin to send GCM notifications to Android app.